# Method to create instance of other class and add it to map

Tags: java, methods, maps

So, I have this class:

```
  public class Person
{

   private String Name;
   private String address;
   private int postCode;

   public Person(String aName, String anAddress, int aPostCode)
   {
      this.Name = aName;
      this.address = anAddress;
      this.postCode = aPostCode;
   }
```

And I have this class:

```
public class MapClass
{
   private Map<String, String> people;

   public Garage()
   {
      people = new HashMap<>();
   }

   public void addperson(String thing1, String name, String address, int area)
   {

   }
}
```

So I need some help writing the 'addPerson()' method. It needs to create an instance of Person and add it to the map referenced by the instance variable 'people' with 'thing1' as the key.

I think that I need to use the 'put' method to do this but I'm really unsure about the syntax here.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: The map referenced by `people` does not accommodate values of type `Person`.  Its values are `String`s.

Comment: Did you look at the Javadocs for `Map` (which include links to its implementing​ types)? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change `private Map<String, String>` to `private Map<String, Person>` .

Then your method will look like:

```
public void addperson(String thing1, String name, String address, int area)
   {
      people.put(thing1, new Person(name, address, area));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
private Map<String, String> people;
```

with:

```
private Map<String, Person> people;
```

This way your value type complies with the person. Then implement your method body like this:

```
public void addperson(String thing1, String name, String address, int area)
   {
     Person person = new person(name, address, area);
     people.put(thing1, person);
   }
```

Here is small tutorial for [Map](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
people.put(thing1, new Person(name, address, area));
```

Your definition of 'people' is however wrong, should be:

```
 private Map<String, Person> people;
```